# Google Index Status drop

Tags: google-search-console

I have recently move to a new hosting, and it seems to have effect on the Google Index Status

[image]

What could cause it?

Comment: Use Fetch as Google to check that Google can see your site okay.

Comment: Please edit the question with more details so users can answer this more specifically, and the question will be helpful to others in the future. For example: Did your domain, URLs, robots.txt directives, meta or headers change? If so, did you follow [these](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049?hl=en) steps outlined by Google? If not, did you follow [these](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033388?hl=en&ref_topic=6033383) steps? Was your site reachable throughout?... After editing the question with more info, it will be placed in the review queue for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

Provided google doesn't think the new domain is a bad domain name or an overly promotional domain name with too many stuffed keywords, the only thing I can think of that can cause a sudden drop in indexing is the moment the real URL is in transition.

Just accept the index dropping for now, and if you still have access to the old URL, make all requests to the old URL redirect to the new URL to minimize loss of indexed pages. For example, if your new domain is example2.com and your old one is example.com, and your page is:

http://example.com/some/section

you can make a redirect to:

http://example2.com/some/section

If your old server runs on apache and you have full access to .htaccess files or even the server config file (httpd.conf), then add these lines in it:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

That will (through redirect) effectively replace example.com with example2.com in the web browser address bar when someone tries to access your site at example.com

After the transition is complete, I would increase the maximum number of requests google is allowed to make to your site via site settings (available from clicking the gear icon on example.com domain) in google's webmaster tools, then I would wait a couple of days.

Its possible that you're trying to have google index the same content on two different sites but it is unaware which domain to use. Thats one reason why I suggested redirecting URLs on the old site to the new site.

Your best option overall is to wait a few days because eventually google will discover the old URLs no longer exist and will remove them from the index.